# Strange characters appearing in input type in html (working on java)

Tags: java, html, jsp

I am filling out certain details in a jsp page and saving those details. Till this point all appears to be fine. But, as soon as i press the back button, the text which i entered in the fields starts showing strange characters like `%AE%20E546%20` in place of `® E546`. Please see the attached images for reference. What may be the cause of this. I have checked the encoding. Using UTF-8 encoding here.
Please help...

*This is the image when i save these details after clicking the save button:*

[image: This is the image when i save these details after clicking the save button]

*This is the image when i click the back button after 1st step:*

[image: This is the image when i click the back button after 1st step]

Comment: If you look closely at the strange characters like "AE" for example, it represents in reality the hexadecimal ASCII code for '®'
Since I have no source code, I can't help you further but you should definitively check on URL encoded.

Comment: Seems like you've encoded this as a URL and did not decode it...

Comment: BTW: The URL is not `UTF-8` encoded. Otherwise it would use `%C2%AE` for `®` instead of `%AE`.

Comment: @fabian: Yes, you are right. Thank you so much. Your comment was very helpful. I got the solution. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 1):

Your values are URL encoded. URL encoding converts characters into a format that can be transmitted over the Internet. Check [this site](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) for more information.

For example ® is encoded as %AE, space as %20 and so on.